# Rename WCF service source file

Tags: c#, wcf

Can we rename the `Service.svc`? When we create a new `WCF Service` the default name is `Service1.svc`. I tried to change it to `CatalogueService.svc` but started getting errors when I tried to run it. Is it because I changed the file name? Do I have to make changes in the files too? And how can I make these changes everywhere at once?
I tried to Update my Service Reference and got error:

> Unable to connect to the remote server. No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: what errors do you get? You can name your services and codefiles as you like

Comment: Find all references of "Service1" in every file in your solution, replace those, should be enough.

Comment: Do you update adress in your client? Now is `.../CatalogueService.svc`

Comment: where do I need to updated this?

Comment: @HumaAli In client reference configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update configuration in your client service reference.
You have `../Service1.svc` but should be `.../CatalogueService.svc`

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

1) Delete Default Service1.cs file.
2) Add new Class file-> Rename it.
3) Implement that interface.

```
class YourNewClassName:IService1
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

or **CLICK YES to this option**

[image]

Comment: How will that work? Now you have an orphaned .svc file

Comment: Follow this     ---      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924403(v=vs.110).aspx